# issue about python3 import package

Tags: python

I hardly know the mechanism of python3 import package.
Structure as followed:

```
Test\
     -A.py
     \ Test1
      -- B.py
      -- C.py
```

A.py

```
from test1.B import hello_b
hello_b()
```

B.py

```
from C import hello_c
def hello_b():
    print("i'm B")
    hello_c()
```

C.py

```
def hello_c():
    print("I'm C")
```

I try: `python A.py` shows that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C'`

I have try `sys.path.append`, but sometimes it's not so cute. 
What's the best way to deal with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Relative imports work a bit different in python3 than in python2. Either use `from test1.C import hello_c` or `from .C import hello_c`

Comment: give full path i.e in A.py `from Test.test1.B import hello_b`. Also chek your current directory by `print(sys.path)` to see Test directory included or not at index 0, if not then do `sys.path.insert(0,"Path/to/Test directory/")` similar in other file file i.e in B.py `from  Test.test1.C import hello_c`